# How to have two different text colors for PagerTitleStrip?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using a [PagerTitleStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html) inside a ViewPager.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/PagerTitleStrip"
        />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

I have to display n titles on this strip.

```
final int titles[] = {"Title1" , "Title2", "Title3", "Title4"};
```

Here is the style applied on the PagerTitleStrip.

```
<style name="PagerTitleStrip">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Note that there is only one textColor field in the AttributeSet for this ViewGroup.

I want to set two different colors (red and gray), one for the visible page's title (primary title), and second for the pages which are not visible (non-primary title which are partially visible on edges).

Also, during page change, the strip title should change color during the transition.

As per doc, [setNonPrimaryAlpha(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html#setNonPrimaryAlpha(float)) lets you define alpha value for non-primary titles, instead of this, I want different text colors, can anyone help me ?

Comment: I am not sure but you can try to set text color via selector. You may try to states which does work for you. Good luck.

Comment: It's simply not possible. If you wanna do something like this you have to write your own implementation of the PagerTitleStrip.

Comment: @hbansal have you found any solution? Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it through xml, the only thing that you must do is write your color state list:

pager_tab_strip_text_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/background_black_3" android:state_window_focused="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/highlight_gold" android:state_window_focused="true" />

</selector>
```

Put your color state list inside a style:

```
<style name="PagerTabStrip">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/pager_tab_strip_text_selector</item>
    </style>
```

The only thing that you must do is, instead of setting this as an style, set it as a textAppearance, like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/fragment_light_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/fragment_light_pagertabstrip"
            android:textAppearance="@style/PagerTabStrip.Light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: it's works just for text. Don't work for bar indicator or icon.